# To find genes that don't change in RNA-seq, Deseq2 has altHypothesis="lessAbs". Is there a way to make limma do the same thing for proteomics?

Tags: r, rna-seq, differential-expression, proteomics, limma

I love that Deseq2 has altHypothesis="lessAbs" !!!!!!! I've used it a ton for RNA-seq. However, now I'm working with mass spect data using limma. Is there a way to make limma do the same thing?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Could you please [edit] your question and clarify a bit? First, please make the title be a title: a short, concise description of what the question is about. Second, please give us a bit more context. I think limma is an R package, right? And what exactly would this option do? Identify _genes_ that don't change? Between what and what? Are you comparing two sets of mass-spec data? Please add all extra info to your question, don't answer in the comments, just add it to the main question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct support for this by best knowledge. Similar questions have been asked previously in the Bioconductor support forum, for example:

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/64300/#64793

They discuss options around the TOST concept.

For edgeR:

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/66283/#66287

From these posts please go back and forth to find other posts in that forum to capture what the developers of limma/edgeR responded on the matter.

Depending on your exact purpose it might even be enough to go for genes with large AveExpr and a nominal (not adj) p-value close to one.